# End game patrols?

Tags: fallout-4

I heard that if you complete the main quest by siding with the Minutemen, you'll end up with numerous patrols of Minutemen in the Commonwealth, who fight raiders and mutants.

That sounds awesome, but I'm currently siding with the Railroad, and was wondering if there was still a possibility to get those patrols with the Railroad ending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll get patrols from the faction you complete the game with throughout the Commonwealth.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer says, you indeed get patrols of whatever faction you end the game with.

I just wanted to mention a couple of other things, first one being that almost everytime you see a patrol, there is a power armor hidden there. And second, that Diamond City rises over 5 flags of your faction all around the city.